# Boolean Expression Only Showing False Output

Tags: python

I'm self-teaching python and I've experienced an issue for the first time that doesn't have an error message for me to figure out what the heck is wrong with it haha. I'm practicing boolean expressions with a small guessing game and only the false output is showing even if I use the true output. I have a feeling it's a simple problem but it's got me stumped.

```
print("Hello there!")
guess = input("Can you guess my favorite food?")

if guess == "Tacos":
    print("Tacos are life")
else:
    print("GROSS!")
print("Thanks for playing the guessing game!! Go eat TACOS!")
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you show the terminal output you are seeing? Also, try and include code as code blocks in the body of your question in the future rather than linking screenshots.

Comment: Your input prompt string is `"Can you guess my favorite food?"` but I notice in your terminal input there is a space before your answer: `"Can you guess my favorite food?_Tacos"` (using underscore to show the whitespace in question). The strings `" Tacos" != "Tacos"`.

Comment: Simply add the whitespace to your input prompt: `guess = input("Can you guess my favorite food? ")`.

Comment: or `trim()` the input to get rid of whitespace

Comment: you never tried `print(f'@{guess}@')` to see what you are comparing against

Comment: @rioV8 why force the user to manually enter a space?

Comment: @ddejohn where do I force the space? I suggest to take action in case there is a space

Comment: It's just cleaner to include the space in the prompt so that the user doesn't feel the need to add their own ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ just my opinion... Actually, whenever I take user input in my programs I usually include a new line and a prompt symbol of some kind: e.g., `input("Enter your height in inches\n > ")`. I *do* actually strip extraneous whitespace from user input, so I guess I had more of an issue with an "inelegant" input prompt...

Answer (score 0):

I think you may enter a space before your input. so guess will be `" Tacos"` and not
`"Tacos"`. otherwise I think it should work. [the line from your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTz6Y.png)

Comment: You may wish to show the OP _how_ to handle extraneous spaces in input.